# TextView on Button

Tags: android, button, textview

I created a Custom `Button` that and added it a `TextView` programmatically:

```
layout is a `FrameLayout` containing the `Button` and the `TextView`
```

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tv.setTextColor(getContrastColor(left));
        tv.setText(" " + left);
        layout.addView(tv);
```

On my device it works (opo) - I can see the texts but On my emulator (**Nexus 5**) it doesn't - the texts are invisible - maybe below the button.
Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: My emulator is api 21 - android 5 and I saw another android 5 device is having the same problem. my device is android 4.4

Comment: Why are you using a textview on button? Why don't you use the button's text?

Comment: Because I need to - I want to make multiple textViews - each can be somewhere else on the button

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - In android 5 there was a new property - elevation. I needed to check if the SDK was 21 and if so change the elavation of textView